# WinSCP and PuTTY drop out constantly, on other computer they don't?

Tags: ssh, putty, winscp

This has been bothering me for a long time. When I ssh or sftp into my server via PuTTY or WinSCP, it drops out after 2 minutes, then has to reconnect. PuTTY will just lock up and not let me type... it wont say inactive just pure lockup.  WinSCP will say *"host not communicating"* then I press reconnect and it reconnects...

This happens within 3-5 minutes! It's driving me **mad**!

On my other PC, connecting to the same server same version of both programs **it will stay connected for 24 hours**! I even reformatted my PC and still same issue, do you have any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means your server has some connection timeout (try a look at its `sshd_config` file or equivalent).

You can try to play with the "keep alive" options in PuTTY or WinSCP.
Here are my options for some similar case connection:

**PuTTY**:

[image]

**WinSCP**

Open the following dialog by going to your site, clicking *Edit* and *Advanced* and going to [*Connection* page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_connection):

[image]

Comment: Those settings seem to keep putty up. Now for winscp.

Comment: Same logic: connection -> keepalive settings (I edited my answer and add an example, through not tested).

Comment: I was trying to find the settings lol. I was going through preferences  I guess I had to exit it and then I could access the connections. Thanks :)

Comment: I cannot find this on WinScp 5.9.3.

Comment: [Found it at __Sessions/Sites/Site Manager__](https://superuser.com/questions/790364/winscp-has-to-constantly-reconnect-to-my-ubuntu-server#comment1967011_790365)